# Tap a view below a tableview that has a top content inset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to click a table with a content inset to tap the view below it?

Here is the setup:

2 tables view controllers on top of each other.

Top Table
Bottom Table

Top table background is transparent with a top content inset revealing the bottom table.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(150,0,0,0)];
```

When the top table is scrolled all the way down, it does successfully reveal the bottom table view.

However, the bottom table can not receive touch events.

Is it possible to somehow make it clickable? (the cells?)

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Any way I can edit my question?

Comment: Maybe one of these reasons? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved fairly quickly by subclassing the top container and responding with NO if the click was between the empty space.

```
(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Also need to ensure that the table was also not scrolled up by checking it's contentOffset

```
    if (point.y < topPadding)   
    {
        if ((tableView.contentOffset.y * -1) >= topPadding)
        {
            // Point was inside the empty space of the tableview
               return NO;
        }
    }
```